# Entity Framework select and where condition using dynamic parameters

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to select Costumers from my database using entity framework. My Costumers have a Job and a Country and some other attribute (name, sex, age ...).

1- How can I pass a list of job and list of countries as a "where" condition

2- How to dynamically select attributes ( the user can either choose to select one attribute or many)?

I have List proprity; if proprity contains ("Name", "Age") my select will be: select(new {Cosutumer.Name, Costumer.Age}). If proprity contains ("Country", "Job") my select will change to Costumer.Country and Costumer.Job .. etc

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Entity Framework could you not simply pass in the lists as a parameter?

```
public Customer[] GetCustomers(Job[] jobsList, Country[] countryList)
{
    return [yourDataContext].Customers.Where(x => jobsList.Contains(x.Job)).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: thanks, that worked for me. Any idea how I can dynamically select attributes?

Comment: You'll have to expand on what you mean by dynamically select attributes

Comment: Suppose I have 5 attribute for the Table Costumers (ID, Name, Age, Country, Job). Sometimes I want to get only the Names, other times I want the Names and Ages or the Country and the Name. So it's a list with the names of the selected attributes and if the name of the attribute is in that list I will return it

Comment: To retrieve all the names of the customers you could just run the function posted above, then access the names like `Customer.Name`, perhaps in a foreach loop.

Comment: It's not about the name of the Costumers. Maybe I explained it wrong. I'm talking about the properties (attributes)
I have List<String> proprity; if proprity contains ("Name", "Age") my select will be: select(new {Cosutumer.Name, Costumer.Age}). If proprity contains  ("Country", "Job") my select will change to Country and Job.